# ssis script task throws error when run from sql agent job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

When I run this package from Visual Studio, it works fine, but when I run it from the sql agent job (SQL Server 2012 sp1) it throws error on the Script Task . I am running it under a proxy account in the sql agent job.

> Error:  Source: Set FS File Parameters Script Task      Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

The proxy account is configured for the following subsystems:

- ActiveX Script
- SQL Server Analysis Services Command
- SQL Server Analysis Services Query
- SQL Server Analysis Services Package
- PowerShell

I guess it is a problem with the proxy account using System.IO,  because all other packages that do not access the file system are running fine, even though they have script tasks. All file path variables have been set up with UNC paths. The folder and files have everyone full control configuration.

- How do I set it up to run from the sql agent job?
- How do I check to make sure proxy account has access to file system?

Here is the code in the script task:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
#endregion

public void Main()
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::AS_FileArchivePath"].Value = "";
        Dts.Variables["User::ExcludeProvidersArchivePath"].Value = "";
        Dts.Variables["User::AS_FilePath"].Value = "";
        Dts.Variables["User::ExcludeProvidersFilePath"].Value = "";
        Dts.Variables["User::FeeScheduleFileName"].Value = "";
        Dts.Variables["User::FileArchivePath"].Value = "";


        //get load file name
        String dirPath = Dts.Variables["User::FileDropFolder"].Value.ToString();
        String fileExt = Dts.Variables["User::LoadFileExt"].Value.ToString();
        String FileArchivePath =    Dts.Variables["User::FileArchiveFolder"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::FileArchiveDateFolder"].Value.ToString();
        String FileName = "";
        String FileType = "";
        int FileSize = 0;
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            if (file.Extension.Contains(fileExt)
                && file.Name.StartsWith("DoNotDeleteTemplate") == false
                && file.Name.Contains("Products") == true
                && file.Name.Contains("Special") == false
                && file.Name.Contains("Exclude") == false)
            {
                FileName = file.Name;
                FileSize = (int)file.Length;
                FileType = file.Extension;
            }
        }


        if (FileName != "")
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::FeeScheduleFileName"].Value = FileName;
            Dts.Variables["User::FeeScheduleFileSize"].Value = FileSize;
            Dts.Variables["User::FeeScheduleFileType"].Value = FileType;

            //create archive folder
            bool folderExists = Directory.Exists(FileArchivePath);
            if (!folderExists)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(FileArchivePath);

            //set full archive path
            Dts.Variables["User::FileArchivePath"].Value = FileArchivePath + "\\" + FileName;


            //set full load file path
            String filePath = Dts.Variables["User::FileDropFolder"].Value.ToString() + FileName;

        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: have you checked the eventviewer on the file server you are trying to read / write on? Also try to put a try / catch block on your script so you can see a detailed error.

Comment: Works in Visual Studio, doesn't work as a job? All packages except ones with file access work? Despite it seeming that user access is set up correctly.. it isn't. If you want a brute force solution, use ProcMon to identify which file/folder has an access issue.

Comment: I did the following:Opened Component Services,Expand Component Service->My Computer->DCOM Config, Locate “Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 11.0” Rt click and select “Properties”
Select the “Security” tab, In Launch and Activate Permissions, then “Edit” Grant “Local Launch”, “Local Activation” permissions for SQL Agent Service / proxy account MyDomain\MyAcct, Restarted SQL Agent and tried again, now the error in the event viewer is gone, but i still get the error in sysssislog: Source: Set FS File Parameters Script Task: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: I am loosing hope, please respond. I am sure many people are using this in their ETL.

Thanks.

Comment: When I run the package in a scheduled job in SQL Agent using a service account I get this error. I wrapped my code in the script task in a try catch block and I get the error message copied below. I have set everyone full control on the folders on E drive.
Error Message:
Executed as user: MyDomain\MyServiceAcct . Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 11.0.2100.60 for 32-bit Copyright Source: Set FSFileParameters Script Task My File Task Description: Access to the path '\\MyServer\E$\MyFiles\FSP\' is denied. End Error DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).

Comment: sharing the folder solved the problem.